# Images broken in email html body

Tags: html, image, email, base64

I am expecting a problem with images in emails.

I am sending html emails with sendmail. I have all needed headers correctly.
Inside the html there is an image tag with correct base64 string I got from an online encoder:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACUAAABACAYAAACdp77qAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQ    BZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/I 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">
```

When I was testing the email on my localhost, the emails where sent and the image was displayed correctly.

But now I have deployed the functionality on our development server and everything was damaged. The emails are received, but the image is broken. When I look into email raw data, I see that it added "!" signs and new lines inside the image data.

Am I correct that it has something to do with server mail configuration? Or is it something else?

Comment: take a look at this http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/my-images-wont-upload-cant-preview-images#broke

Comment: hmmm... it has nothing about base64 included images... does it mean I better change the source to full image urls? I thought base64 was the correct option.

Comment: Usually images are web hosted using normal urls. Unless you have a reason not to, I'd suggest just including standard links.

Comment: ok, I converted my code to use urls and not base64 data. So it works as needed.